# How to compute n choose k modulo a prime power efficiently using extended Lucas' Theorem?

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory, algorithms

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Lucas Theorem but without prime numbers](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/60206/lucas-theorem-but-without-prime-numbers)

This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13146654/calculated-ncr-mod-m-n-choose-r-for-large-values-of-n-109) mentions a strategy for computing C(n, k) modulo a composite number, but leaves out the details. The use of the Chinese Remainder Theorem is standard, but I don't follow the suggestion for how to use the extended version of Lucas' Theorem to compute C(n, k) mod p^q.

Comment: Thanks, but this link is for Lucas' original Theorem, which only works for primes. I understand Lucas' original Theorem reasonably well.

Comment: Maybe [this answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/60221/139) is what you're after?

Comment: I saw that answer, but it's still a bit opaque to me how that translates into a working algorithm.

Comment: Well the answer includes a link to a paper which goes into a little detail on how to turn it into an algorithm.

Comment: You saw the above answer, but did *not* link to it in your question and did not elaborate what you did not understand. This makes it impossible to give you a better answer that is not already in the other thread.