# If $p\geq 5$ is Prime, Prove that $\binom{p^2}{p}-p$ is a multiple of $p^5$

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, binomial-coefficients, divisibility

If $p\geq 5$ is Prime, Prove that $$\binom{p^2}{p}-p$$ is a multiple of $p^5$

I started using the fact that:
$$\binom{n}{r}=\frac{n}{r}\binom{n-1}{r-1}$$
So we have:
$$\binom{p^2}{p}-p=\frac{p^2}{p}\binom{p^2-1}{p-1}-p=p\left(\binom{p^2-1}{p-1}-1\right)$$
Now it suffices to prove that:
$$\binom{p^2-1}{p-1}-1$$ is divisible by $p^4$
Any help from here?

Comment: Divisibility by $p$ follows from Wilson's theorem

Comment: Sounds like generalized Lucas thm is what you need: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/60206/lucas-theorem-but-without-prime-numbers

Comment: [Mathematical Omnibus](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Mathematical-Omnibus-Lectures-Mathematics-non/dp/0821843168), page 37, *Theorem 2.7 (A. Schwarz, 1959)*.

Comment: Here is a [PDF](http://members.unine.ch/felix.schlenk/Daejeon/Fuchs.Taba.omnibus.pdf).

Answer (score 1):

It is perhaps interesting, that this congruence follows from other well known congruences in the literature. The result is attributed to Schwarz, who seems to have proven it first in $1959$ (see the link above).

First,
Jacobsthal proved $1952$ in the paper *On the divisibility of the difference between two binomial coefficients* the following result, for all $c\le b\le a$, and any prime $p\ge 5$,
$$
\binom{p^a}{p^b}\equiv \binom{p^{a-c}}{p^{b-c}}\bmod p^{3+a+2b-3c}.
$$
For $(a, b,c)=(2,1,1)$ we obtain
$$
\binom{p^2}{p}\equiv p \bmod p^{4}.
$$
This can be found in the paper [Wolstenholme's Theorem](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1111.3057.pdf). There one can also find the result by Helou and Terjanian
in $2008$, which says that
$$
\binom{np}{mp}\equiv \binom{n}{m}\bmod p^k,
$$
where $k$ is the exact power of $p$ dividing $p^3mn(n-m)\binom{n}{m}$.
For $n=p$ and $m=1$ this yields
$$
\binom{p^2}{p}\equiv p \bmod p^{5}.
$$